# Does anyone know of any brokerages that allow trades to be placed in prices out to the 5th decimal place?

Tags: trading

I have owned a penny stock for a while now that typically trades between \$0.0002 and \$0.0003. The thing is, though, that it most frequently trades BETWEEN those two price points and doesn't actually hit them very often. The platform I use to trade (along with any others I've so far investigated) only allow trading out to the 4th decimal place.

I figure someone somewhere has to allow trades out to the 5th decimal place or the stock price couldn't be fluctuating within that range. It affects the value of the stock. It makes me gain or lose X amount of dollars throughout any given day. I'd like to be able to make trades with it, but since the price doesn't often hit either of those marks it really limits what I can do with it.
So, is someone aware of a trading platform that trades out to the 5th decimal place?

Answer (score 1):

The major problem is you are assuming there is liquidity out there at 5 decimal places.  Chances are such a stock 'trades by appointment'and the apparent fluctuations are driven by unique situations.

Also, your transactions costs are going to be outrageous w.r.t. price.  Imagine you trade 1,000,000 shares at .00002.Someone must handle all million shares when the value is only in the hundreds or thousands of dollars.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know your country, context and exchange you are trading, I can only speculate.

But a my guess would be that no one has placed an order with more than 5 decimal places. I guess that someone has trade, through a dealer, a block trade of a certain amount N of shares for a total price of X. When you divide X by N you happened to have more than 5 places.